# Getting the area of the two different image parts of UIImage

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

[image]

This is UIImage that i am showing on the image view . My requirement is to get the area of these two different shapes separately in term of the pixels .I have tried a lot. Currently I am getting the addition of the pixels enclosed by those two areas. How can i get this areas differently is there any library or algorithm to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I have done something similar in C. There is a simple algorithm, you might be interested in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling